# grunt windows 7 path issue

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, command-line-interface

I  have node.js  installed and  using `npm install -g grunt` I managed to install grunt  files. The process works well  till now, but I run grunt command  it  is throwing me batch file error. what could be the reason? I did installed phonegap and it is able to find/set path easily but where as GRUNT not working,   Pls help .

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Comment: We cannot guess what error you get. please provide more information such as the error message!

Comment: it's  batch error means -   'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 6):

From the the [Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started):

- First, you need to install the grunt CLI, `npm install -g grunt-cli`;
- Then, install grunt `npm install grunt --save-dev` (you don't need the `--save-dev` option if you don't want to include it in your `package.json` file).